# nginx variable port number

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'd like to be able tu run an nginx server on port 8080 when launched by a regular user and on port 80 when launched by root. How can this be parametrized in the config file or by using bash script ?

Comment: Remove any listen directive. Nginx defaults are exactly what you want.

Comment: That's it, thanks. Note that the default port is 8000 and not 8080.

Comment: You should change that comment to an answer, @AlexeyTen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you like to provide configuration files by commandline, check out the commandline help:

```
$ /usr/sbin/nginx -h
nginx version: nginx/1.2.1
Usage: nginx [-?hvVtq] [-s signal] [-c filename] [-p prefix] [-g directives]

Options:
  -?,-h         : this help
  -v            : show version and exit
  -V            : show version and configure options then exit
  -t            : test configuration and exit
  -q            : suppress non-error messages during configuration testing
  -s signal     : send signal to a master process: stop, quit, reopen, reload
  -p prefix     : set prefix path (default: /etc/nginx/)
  -c filename   : set configuration file (default: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)
  -g directives : set global directives out of configuration file
```

So maybe you're looking for the `-c` option here.

Comment: I wanted to avoid rewriting an entire configuration file for this single purpose. @Alexey-Ten 's solution is what i was looking for.